# Java security risk?

Tags: java

Why is this code considered dangerous or vulnerable?

```
String sFileName = request.getParameter("fName");
if (sFileName.toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf"))
// open file
else
// don’t open the file
```

Comment: Please take a look at the **[help center](https://security.stackexchange.com/help)** before asking a question.

Comment: @Insane: Is your comment aimed at the bad formatting of the question or the topic in general? Because I found the question and especially the answer by fbo3264 to be very interesting. Just curious.

Comment: @hamena314 Both. Considered by who? More details in general? And of course, the bad formatting. Also because the snippet looks like a direct rip from this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12926229/3893016).

Comment: SafetyNetter, are you asking about this comment: "It's generally dangerous to run PDFs downloaded from the internet from the local filesystem" There are lots of reasons why it *could* be dangerous, but it's difficult to narrow it down for you without context.

Comment: Who considers this dangerous? What is the context that it is run in? What does "open file" mean? Is it opened on the server? Sent as part of the requestt? Other?

Comment: I think in this case it is quite important that the java version is mentioned

Answer (score 1):

Apart from path traversal attacks this code could be vulnerable to Null-Byte injection. For more information read [this](http://blog.portswigger.net/2008/05/null-byte-attacks-are-alive-and-well.html).

Update:

As Maarten Bodewes pointed out, this has been fixed since Java 1.7.0_40. I remember this being a vulnerability in 1.6 though.
Anyway when you take a look at the source code for the `File` class you find that the `isInvalid()` method has been added which does the null-byte check:

```
final boolean isInvalid() {
    if (status == null) {
        status = (this.path.indexOf('\u0000') < 0) ? PathStatus.CHECKED
                                                   : PathStatus.INVALID;
    }
    return status == PathStatus.INVALID;
}
```

See also this post on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18995530/preventing-null-byte-attacks-java).

Comment: This is a very light answer, where the bulk of the answer is in a link. Can you include the relevant parts of the link in your answer?

Comment: A quick search found that null-byte injection was fixed in 1.7 b40.

Answer (score 0):

Right now I see 2 problems with this code, Depending on the context.

- The fact that the filename ends with `.pdf` does not mean it is a PDF
  file. Which could lead to all kinds of trouble.
- Malicious code can be hidden in macros of PDF files.

But like I said, it all depends on the context.